# how to connect okhttp client to dynamic proxy list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, okhttp

hi I'm trying to create a spring boot application and I need to send a Post request to Foreign server and I want to send all of the requests with a different IP to other requests I really tried to not ask this question but I did not find anything useful for my problem

I tried to get free proxies from this https://api.getproxylist.com/proxy then connect to them this way :

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,new InetSocketAddress("Address",port));
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .proxy(proxy)
                .build();
```

I expect to connect to the proxy server but I'm getting this two error and I really don't know why : 
Malformed reply from SOCKS server
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on null